# Exit from an application in an OS without memory separation

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

I am writing a monolithic OS(It is a joke to call it an OS but it does have very minimal, school level functionalists). 
When I say monolithic, I meant, it is compiled as a single binary blob and no support for file system etc. Currently I just have a rudimentary simple user space which is nothing but infinite while loop.

I am planning to make my OS little more useful and want to able to write user apps which can terminate like regular apps on a full blown OS.

I don't have glibc or equivalent. My current library in the user space is code which I have written. 
Now my problem is how to add a framework for user space apps, which would let them terminate in a fix point.

I do know how programs get compiled on regular systems and what happens when a program terminates. However, in my case I don't have luxury to compile programs against libraries and if a program terminates then my instruction pointer just goes on a wild detour.

Currently I am making all apps to make to do a "return call" and I am pre-populating the app stack with a fix address(during launch). ***Is there any better way to handle the problem?***

Along with the answer, I would be more than happy to get clarity on some of OS concepts.

I am working on x86 emulator-platform and compiling my binary statically. (I do have virtual memory support)

Comment: I'm pretty certain early version of Linux were a joke as well. Don't be so quick to self-deprecate :-)

Comment: Are you asking about a specific problem with the app stack, or are you asking about something else?

Comment: I am asking about solutions on app termination in a fixed address. Currently I have taken a route where every app has a fixed return address which I populate onto the stack. Now, I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hand crafting the first stack frame with a return into whatever process cleanup code you need to run seems like a perfectly reasonable method.  If your OS has "syscalls" then user-space process cleanup code (maybe called `exit()`) probably ends with a call to the `_exit()` syscall.  You still need to handle the case where the program tries to execute code in ''la-la land'' because that can still happen (however doing that before you have a page-protection system might be a hard problem).

Comment: Yep, my current solution is exactly like what you have mentioned. My every app does return to a fixed address and it lands up in a routine which is equivalent of exit. Then I go and make a syscall and do necessary user space and kernel space cleanup for that app. However, I can't have an app which does not do a return.("ret call" in x86 land). I am trying to achieve that with some some hackery.

Comment: You can have apps that don't return in pretty much every OS: `int main(void) { do {} while(1); }`

Comment: Oh may be my wording was not right. I cant have an app like this void main(void){int j = 2;}. As exit of this app goes in La La Land. However int main(void){int j=2; return;} does not cause any issue as it has a return statement which takes me to a cleanup routine.

Comment: In other systems, `main` isn't really the entry point of your program -- essentially, a blob like: `void REAL_MAIN() { int v = main(argc, argv);` exit(v); }` is linked into your code.